# Axios CORS Post Request Error

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, jwt

Пытаюсь реализовать jwt авторизацию,есть https://elepsio.herokuapp.com/auth/login возвращает токен

> Поля username = test password = test

Но при авторизации выбивает CORS ошибку,на сервер хедеры установлены,в чем проблема ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const SignInComponent = () => {
const signIn = useSignIn()
const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({username: '', password: ''})

const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('https://elepsio.herokuapp.com/auth/login', formData)
        .then((res)=>{
            if(res.status === 200){
                if(signIn({token: res.data.token, 
                           expiresIn:res.data.expiresIn,
                           tokenType: "Bearer",
                           authState: res.data.authUserState})){
                    // Redirect or do-something
                }else {
                    console.log("Pizda")
                }
            }
        })
}

return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type={"text"} onChange={(e)=>setFormData({...formData, username: e.target.value})}/>
        <input type={"password"} onChange={(e)=>setFormData({...formData, password: e.target.value})}/>
       <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: Использую кит для авторизации React Auth Kit https://authkit.arkadip.co/usage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме заголовка `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` в ответе вашего сервера должно быть кое-что ещё.

Перед любым запросом на сервер, сокет (ip + порт) которого отличается от сокета, который открыт в текущей вкладке, браузер хочет убедиться в безопасности запроса. Он автоматически отправляет на сервер `OPTIONS` запрос, т.е. как бы спрашивая уместно ли отправлять на сервер сейчас запросы? И если да, то какие методы нужно использовать? Ваш сервер должен отправить ответ, где содержится заголовок `Allow`. В этом заголовке должны быть перечислены методы, которые поддерживает сервер (например `GET` и `POST`).

Если браузер получит соответствующий ответ о том, что CORS поддерживается, запросы уместны, то сразу после `OPTIONS` он отправит ваш запрос, иначе будет ошибка, которую вы сейчас наблюдаете

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,понял в чём проблема.